# Ruby HTTParty - get the redirected URL

Tags: http, ruby-on-rails-4, httparty, ruby-2.2

I am trying to send an HTTP request using **HTTParty** with some parameters,

Eg:

```
GET URL: http://example1.com?a=123&b=456

response_to_get = HTTParty.get('http://example1.com?a=123&b=456')
```

The **redirect_url** for this particular request is http://example2.com

When I tried the URL `http://example1.com?a=123&b=456` in browser, it redirects to the expected URL with parameter value appended to it like `http://example2.com?c=123trt58`, but when I did it using HTTParty, I'm  getting an HTML reponse only.

My requirement is to get the **URL**(http://example2.com?c=123trt58) out from the response.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 9):

If you do not want to follow redirects, but still want to know where the page is redirecting to (useful for web crawlers, for example), you can use `response.headers['location']`:

```ruby
response = HTTParty.get('http://httpstat.us/301', follow_redirects: false)

if response.code >= 300 && response.code < 400
    redirect_url = response.headers['location']
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Slightly corrected @High6 answer:

```
    res = HTTParty.head("example1.com?a=123&b=456")
    res.request.last_uri.to_s
```

This will prevent large response download. Just read headers.

Answer (score 2):

To get the final URL after a redirect using `HTTParty` you can use:

```
res = HTTParty.get("http://example1.com?a=123&b=456")
res.request.last_uri.to_s

# response should be 'http://example2.com?c=123trt58'
```

Comment: Right choice is res = HTTParty.head("http://example1.com?a=123&b=456")  HTTParty.get will download all content even that is 100Mb video file.

Comment: @AivilsŠtoss you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

url = URI("https://<whatever>")

req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port, :use_ssl => true) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}

res['location']
```

PS: This is using native ruby HTTP lib.